# How to create a ContentAlignment control outside of PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I want to create a ContentAlignment control outside of a PropertyGrid control.
How can I do this without creating a control from scratch and using instead the one included in .NET framework 4.5 ?

[image]

Comment: What is that button supposed to do?  Open a dialog with sorting and filtering options?  I assume this is WPF.

Comment: No, it's not WPF, it is a normal Winforms application. I need this control to let the user choose the alignment of text on an image.

Comment: You ought to be able to lay a button right on top of the PropertyGrid control.

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title of your questions.  Google already indexes the most common tag (in this case c#) at the beginning of the title, so your addition of the tag in the title is redundant.  The SO community has already discussed the issue of tags in titles and has established a broad consensus that they don't belong there; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: Ok, I put that in order to be recognized by users, so that they know it's about c#